# Как правильно выразиться?

Tags: грамотная-речь

1. Кларнеты изготовлены (сконструированы,выполнены, сделаны) в строе B

Answer (score 0):

Можно выбирать между первыми двумя вариантами, в зависимости от того, насколько обычен полученный результат (строй В): если он при желании достигается известными средствами, можно сказать "выполнен", если же потребовались оригинальные технические решения, то предпочтительно "сконструирован".

Нельзя исключить и третий вариант (изготовлен, сделан) - если нужное свойство достигается перестройкой или незначительной доработкой конструкции, изготовленной по чертежам.

Comment: А если речь не о процессе изготовления, а о распространенности. "Большинство кларнетов выполнено в строе B?" Корректно ли так выразиться. Или в таких случаях технологический процесс не стоит затрагивать? "Большинство кларнетов имеют строй B?"

Comment: Да, тогда подойдёт ваше последнее предложение.